# Lazy Loading doesn't work for Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, lazy-loading

I have implemented lazy load from David Walsh's tips here (tip 1) https://www.sitepoint.com/five-techniques-lazy-load-images-website-performance/ and it works great on a fresh load of the site. But it doesn't work when the images are filtered and re-rendered with an ajax request. I'm using Rails and the images are contained in a partial which is re-rendered on an ajax request on a click of the filter. When the images are filtered through the ajax request only the blurry placeholder image loads and not the actual image.

My js code is

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('img[data-src]'), function(img) {
  img.setAttribute('src', img.getAttribute('data-src'));
  img.onload = function() {
  img.removeAttribute('data-src');
  };
});
```

My image code is

```
<%=image_tag(activity.lead_image.xs_thumb, :class => "card-img-top", :alt => "Card image cap", data: { "src" => image_path(activity.lead_image.thumb) }) %>
```

Any steer will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript is run one-time at page load, when your ajax request happens you have a new set of img tags which haven't been evaluated.

You likely want to invoke your lazy-loading Javascript *again* after your ajax call. You could encapsulate your JS within a function, and invoke it after your ajax call has completed.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried $('#typemask a').on('click', function(){
      $('.pages_index img').setAttribute('src', img.getAttribute('data-src'));
      img.onload = function() {
      img.removeAttribute('data-src');
      };
    }); => console log says img not recognised
and $(document).ajaxComplete(function(evt){
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('img[data-src]'), function(img) {
      img.setAttribute('src', img.getAttribute('data-src'));
      img.onload = function() {
      img.removeAttribute('data-src');
      };
    });
}); => nothing happens